# How many vectors can be "close to mutual orthogonal like 80 degrees" in a high dimensional space?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

100 dimensional space only allows exactly 100 vectors to be mutually orthogonal (90 degrees). 
What if we lose the constraint to “close to mutually orthogonal” (e.g., 80 degrees), can we find huge huge amount of such vectors ?

Comment: Probably still just $100$ since the pairwise almost orthogonality will probably force independence. I'd need to think this through carefully to be sure.

Comment: It really blows up in large dimensions. You may want to study *spherical codes*. There are constructions of for example $2^{2n}$, $n$ even, vectors  $\in\{\pm1\}^{2^n-1}$ such that the inner products of the vectors are in the range $[-2^{n/2+1},2^{n/2+1}]$. So if $\theta$ is the angle between a pair of vectors then $|\cos\theta|\le 2^{1-n/2}$. For $n=8$, i.e. dimension $255$, this gives (barring a numerical mistake by me) roughly $2^{16}$ vectors with angles between $83$ and $97$ degrees.

Comment: [The Gold sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_code) are perhaps the most widely known such families of vectors due to their use in GPS synchronization. Not sure how much Unlight I can shed on the question now. It's getting late here, and I have been cherishing my Talisker for a while. Anyway, for a sequence of dimensions of the form roughly a power of two, say $n\approx2^\ell$, and an exponent $t\in\Bbb{N}$ we can construct families $S(n,t)$ of $n^{t+1}$ vectors such that $\max|\cos\theta|\to0$ as $\ell\to\infty$.

Comment: Thanks. I was stupid to forget Golden code .... Yes, "Golden code v.s. Walsh-Hadamard code" is a perfect example here.

Comment: Nothing "stupid" about it. Our geometric intuition is dominated, or *limited*, by the low-dimensional pictures we can see.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen Not sure you can see my comment here. I am looking for the proof of your statement (I trust they are correct). Would you recommend some text book or paper for the proof ? Thanks

Comment: Bill, I added an answer to your other question. The argument with the Gold code is very similar even though there are also some differences.

Comment: Basically there will be two(and in the case of other variant families up to four)  choices of $z$ leading to a non-vanishing inner sum, and the coefficient of $256$ increases accordingly. This is explained in the Handbook of Coding Theory on chapters on sequences and/or number theory.

Comment: Hey @JyrkiLahtonen Would you have reference like a paper or a book, for these equations ? Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you not find *Handbook of Coding Theory* in a university library near you? It is a bit pricey to buy one for personal use.

Answer (score 1):

Take a projective plane of order $9$ which exists since $9$ is a prime power.  There are $9^2 + 9 + 1 = 91$ points and the same number of lines.  The incidence vectors of the lines form a family of $91$ $(0,1)$-vectors in a space of the same dimension, and each of the line incidence vectors has exactly $10$ $1$s, corresponding to the subset of $10$ points which lie on the line.

By definition of projective plane, each distinct pair of lines intersects in a single point.  One can now replace each of the vectors by the $2^{10}$ possible signed versions.

The resulting quasiorthogonal set of "ternary" vectors (i.e., with entries in $\{-1,0,+1\}$) has $91 * 2^{10} = 93,184$ elements. As $\arccos(1/10) \approx 84.26 \deg.$, only a $5.74 \deg$ deviation from strict orthogonality is needed to achieve a $1024$-fold inflation in the size of a pairwise-nearly-orthogonal set.

Comment: Oops! The idea is right but I was off in a key detail.  The multiple ternary vectors corresponding to one 0/1 vector need to also obey suitable pairwise angle constraints.  Using a 12 x 12 Hadamard matrix and dropping two cols one gets a system of termary vectors with at worst arccos(1/5), i.e., around 11.5 deg., and the inflation is 12-fold.  So my answer above with this correction gives a simple but much more modest way to  improve on strict orthogonality..